# how can I set the navigation section to fixed after being scrolled and when it reach at top-0 position

Tags: html, jsx, tailwind-css

I have used this code and I want to set the nav section at fixed position when it is scrolled and reach to the top

```
  <div className='w-full'>
{/* top section */}
        <div className='flex justify-center'>
            <div className='w-9/12 h-72  bg-gray-200 '>
                <div className='text-3xl font-normal w-full h-2/4 flex justify-center items-center '>Meranda</div>
////// nav section
                <div className='flex w-full h-2/4 justify-center items-center'>
                        <div className='mr-8'>HOME</div>
                        <div className='mr-8'>CATEGORIES</div>
                        <div className='mr-8'>POLITICS</div>
                        <div className='mr-8'>BUSINESS</div>
                        <div className='mr-8'>HEALTH</div>
                        <div className='mr-8'>DESIGN</div>
                        <div className='mr-8'>SPORT</div>
                        <div className='mr-8'>CONTACT</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{/* bottom section */}
        <div className='w-full  flex justify-center'>
            <div className='w-9/12 h-screen bg-slate-500'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS position `sticky` with a `top` property of `0`. This can be utilised by the Tailwind [sticky](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position#sticky-positioning-elements) class. From the docs:

> Use sticky to position an element as relative until it crosses a specified threshold, then treat it as fixed until its parent is off screen.

Your nav section would look like:

```html
<div className='sticky top-0 flex w-full h-2/4 justify-center items-center'>
    <div className='mr-8'>HOME</div>
    <div className='mr-8'>CATEGORIES</div>
    <div className='mr-8'>POLITICS</div>
    ...
</div>
```

You'll need to ensure that the nav element's parent has a height the full size of the document.

Comment: still nothing changed